# Как скрывать блок при нажатии на кнопку? JS

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю Квиз\Тест\Опросник.

Возникла проблема с скрытием родительного блока кнопки при нажатии на эту самую кнопку.
Кнопка открывает дополнительные вопросы при нажатии по атрибутам dataset и id вопросов. Вопросы появляются, но не скрывается блок предыдущего вопроса.

Пробовал находить его через .parentNode, но возвращался undefine.
Отслеживал блоки методом contains на наличие скрывающего класса, но это не дало результата.

```js
function coopQuiz() {
    // Блоки вопросов
    const coopQuizQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.cooperation-quiz-questions');

    // Линия прогресса
    const coopQuizProgress = document.querySelector('.cooperation-quiz__block__progress-line');

    // Кнопки
    const quizBtnPrev = document.querySelectorAll('[data-quiz-prev]');
    const quizBtnNext = document.querySelectorAll('[data-quiz-next]');
    
    // Скрываю все блоки, и показываю только первый
    for(let i = 0; i < coopQuizQuestions.length; i++) {
        coopQuizQuestions[i].classList.add('_hidden')
        coopQuizQuestions[0].classList.remove('_hidden');
    };

    // Кнопка "Далее" 
    // Ищем блок вопроса по метаду dataset и id, удаляем класс _hidden
    quizBtnNext.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            // Ищем кнопку по атрибуту dataset 
            const quizBtnNextId = this.dataset.quizNext;
    
            // Ищем блок вопроса по атрибуту кнопки, что мы нашли, и по id 
            const coopQuizQuestionsId = document.querySelector('#' + quizBtnNextId);
                    
            // Удаляем класс _hidden
            coopQuizQuestionsId.classList.remove('_hidden');
            coopQuizProgress.value++;
        })
    });
    
    // Кнопка "Назад" 
    // Ищем блок вопроса по метаду dataset и id, удаляем класс _hidden
    quizBtnPrev.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            // Ищем кнопку по атрибуту dataset 
            const quizBtnPrevId = this.dataset.quizPrev;
    
            // Ищем блок вопроса по атрибуту кнопки, что мы нашли, и по id 
            const coopQuizQuestionsId = document.querySelector('#' + quizBtnPrevId);
                    
            // Удаляем класс _hidden
            coopQuizQuestionsId.classList.remove('_hidden');
            coopQuizProgress.value--;
        })
    });
};
coopQuiz();
```

```css
.cooperation-quiz-questions._hidden {
  display: none;
}

.cooperation-quiz-questions {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress">
              <progress class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress-line" max="4" value="1"></progress>
              <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress-bg">
                <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress-bar"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="cooperation-quiz__block">
              <form action="#" class="cooperation-quiz__block__form">
                <!-- Вопрос 1 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-1" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>1. Ваша сфера деятельности</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-1" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-1" class="contact-form__radio-label">Руководитель отдела продаж</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-2" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-2" class="contact-form__radio-label">Юрист</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-3" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-3" class="contact-form__radio-label">Бизнес-тренер</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-4" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-4" class="contact-form__radio-label">Предприниматель, бизнесмен</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-5" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-5" class="contact-form__radio-label">Консалтинг</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-7" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input"
                        placeholder="Свой вариант ответа">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-questions-2">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Вопрос 2 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-2" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>2. Ваш регион</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-8" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input" placeholder="Регион">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-prev btn" data-quiz-prev="cooperation-quiz-questions-1">
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                      Назад
                    </button>
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-questions-3">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Вопрос 3 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-3" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>3. Количество клиентов</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-9" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-prev btn" data-quiz-prev="cooperation-quiz-questions-2">
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                      Назад
                    </button>
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-questions-4">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Вопрос 4 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-4" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>4. Удобное время для встречи в Zoom</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-10" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input" placeholder="12:00">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-prev btn" data-quiz-prev="cooperation-quiz-questions-3">
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                      Назад
                    </button>
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-result">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом closest.

```js
function coopQuiz() {
    // Блоки вопросов
    const coopQuizQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.cooperation-quiz-questions');

    // Линия прогресса
    const coopQuizProgress = document.querySelector('.cooperation-quiz__block__progress-line');

    // Кнопки
    const quizBtnPrev = document.querySelectorAll('[data-quiz-prev]');
    const quizBtnNext = document.querySelectorAll('[data-quiz-next]');
    
    // Скрываю все блоки, и показываю только первый
    for(let i = 0; i < coopQuizQuestions.length; i++) {
        coopQuizQuestions[i].classList.add('_hidden')
        coopQuizQuestions[0].classList.remove('_hidden');
    };

    // Кнопка "Далее" 
    // Ищем блок вопроса по метаду dataset и id, удаляем класс _hidden
    quizBtnNext.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            // Ищем кнопку по атрибуту dataset 
            const quizBtnNextId = this.dataset.quizNext;
    
            // Ищем блок вопроса по атрибуту кнопки, что мы нашли, и по id 
            const coopQuizQuestionsId = document.querySelector('#' + quizBtnNextId);
                    
            // Удаляем класс _hidden
            coopQuizQuestionsId.classList.remove('_hidden');
            coopQuizProgress.value++;
            
            // Ищем родительский блок и добавляем ему класс _hidden
            this.closest('.cooperation-quiz-questions').classList.add('_hidden');
        })
    });
    
    // Кнопка "Назад" 
    // Ищем блок вопроса по метаду dataset и id, удаляем класс _hidden
    quizBtnPrev.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            // Ищем кнопку по атрибуту dataset 
            const quizBtnPrevId = this.dataset.quizPrev;
    
            // Ищем блок вопроса по атрибуту кнопки, что мы нашли, и по id 
            const coopQuizQuestionsId = document.querySelector('#' + quizBtnPrevId);
                    
            // Удаляем класс _hidden
            coopQuizQuestionsId.classList.remove('_hidden');
            coopQuizProgress.value--;
            
            // Ищем родительский блок и добавляем ему класс _hidden
            this.closest('.cooperation-quiz-questions').classList.add('_hidden');
        })
    });
};
coopQuiz();
```

```css
.cooperation-quiz-questions._hidden {
  display: none;
}

.cooperation-quiz-questions {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress">
              <progress class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress-line" max="4" value="1"></progress>
              <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress-bg">
                <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__progress-bar"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="cooperation-quiz__block">
              <form action="#" class="cooperation-quiz__block__form">
                <!-- Вопрос 1 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-1" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>1. Ваша сфера деятельности</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-1" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-1" class="contact-form__radio-label">Руководитель отдела продаж</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-2" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-2" class="contact-form__radio-label">Юрист</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-3" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-3" class="contact-form__radio-label">Бизнес-тренер</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-4" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-4" class="contact-form__radio-label">Предприниматель, бизнесмен</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="select-5" name="quesh1" type="radio"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input contact-form__radio-input">
                      <label for="select-5" class="contact-form__radio-label">Консалтинг</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-7" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input"
                        placeholder="Свой вариант ответа">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-questions-2">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Вопрос 2 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-2" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>2. Ваш регион</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-8" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input" placeholder="Регион">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-prev btn" data-quiz-prev="cooperation-quiz-questions-1">
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                      Назад
                    </button>
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-questions-3">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Вопрос 3 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-3" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>3. Количество клиентов</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-9" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-prev btn" data-quiz-prev="cooperation-quiz-questions-2">
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                      Назад
                    </button>
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-questions-4">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Вопрос 4 -->
                <div id="cooperation-quiz-questions-4" class="cooperation-quiz-questions">
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-title">
                    <h6>4. Удобное время для встречи в Zoom</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select">
                    <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item">
                      <input id="service-10" type="text"
                        class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-select-item__input my-input" placeholder="12:00">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cooperation-quiz__block__form-action">
                    <button class="quiz-btn-prev btn" data-quiz-prev="cooperation-quiz-questions-3">
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                      Назад
                    </button>
                    <button class="quiz-btn-next btn" data-quiz-next="cooperation-quiz-result">
                      Далее
                      <div class="button-arrow"></div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)